# How to compute minimum bend radious of NM wire?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

The general rule for computing the minimum band radious states "8 x the overall cable diameter" for single or multiple conductor cables - no metallic shielding.

What does the "overall cable diameter mean" for a NM multi conductor wire?

I have AL 1/0 1/0 1/0 NM cable that seems to be about 1" thick overall. Would it mean 8" MBR?.

If the outside sheething was removed, each separate conductor is about 3/8" so that woud make a 3" bend for eaches?

Comment: Overall means take the biggest dimension.

Comment: Where are you getting 8x from? My NEC doesn't say that....

Comment: You can't shuck cable and handle the wires as individual wires.... unless the individual wires have their own markings, but even then, you have to follow the rules for the individual wires.  E.G. a SE-R cable with *marked* XHHW conductors, XHHW is not allowed loose inside walls.  So you can't unsheath it to make a sharp bend.

Comment: BTW: your cable, once again, is SER cable, *not* NM!

Comment: The 8x width as the radius is for Medium Voltage cables (1,000V and up). there is no minimum bend radius for LV building wire, but there are minimum wire bending SPACE at the terminals that relate to that issue. Table 312.6.

Comment: Ah, right, my bad, I was reading the rule for > 1000V. 
Per 312.6(A) the minimum space at terminal for AL 1/0 is 2.5".
Thank you all for comments! Really helps.

Answer (score 1):

The rule for nm is NEC 334.24 bends in nm and nmc shall be made so the cable will not be damaged. The radius of the curve of the inner edge of any bending during or after install shall not be less than 5 times the diameter of the cable.

The diameter is the thickest area in the direction of the bend (this is different than “fill” where the widest point of the cable is the diameter)

The difference becomes a big deal with flat and under carpet forms of nm.

NM requires the sheath to enter the box 1/4”  beyond the clamp NEC 314.17 so the sheath can not be removed until Inside the box.